# Multiple selects on joined tables with group by?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables with the structures outlined below:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id          BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    username    VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE
);
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id          BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id     BIGINT REFERENCES users(id) NOT NULL,
    category    BIGINT REFERENCES categories(id) NOT NULL,
    text        TEXT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE posts_votes (
    user_id     BIGINT REFERENCES users(id) NOT NULL,
    post_id     BIGINT REFERENCES posts(id) NOT NULL
    value       SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, post_id)
);
```

I was able to compose a query that gets each post with its user and its total value using the below query:

```
SELECT p.id, p.text, u.username, COALESCE(SUM(v.value), 0) AS vote_value
FROM posts p
    LEFT JOIN posts_votes v ON p.id=t.post_id
    JOIN users u ON p.user_id=u.id
WHERE posts.category=1337
GROUP BY p.id, p.text, u.username
```

But now I want to also return a column that returns the result of `SELECT COALESCE((SELECT value FROM posts_votes WHERE user_id=1234 AND post_id=n), 0)` for each post_id `n` in the above query. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: will the value be unique for user_id=1234 and post_id=n?

Comment: `BIGSERIAL` suggests Postgres so I removed the MySQL tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an additional `LEFT JOIN` is a reasonable approach:

```
SELECT p.id, p.text, u.username, COALESCE(SUM(v.value), 0) AS vote_value,
       COALESCE(pv.value, 0)
FROM posts p JOIN
     users u
     ON p.user_id=u.id LEFT JOIN
     topics_votes v
     ON p.id = t.post_id LEFT JOIN
     post_votes pv
     ON pv.user_id = 1234 AND pv.post_id = p.id
WHERE p.category = 1337
GROUP BY p.id, p.text, u.username, pv.value;
```

Comment: Just realized I had a typo in my original post. Is this still the best approach if I'd be `LEFT JOIN`ing the same table twice?

Comment: @jhhayashi . . . Probably the same approach.  If performance is an issue, you might want to pay attention to indexes.